# GDB keeps crashing

Tags: c, gdb

My program is going through an infinite loop and I'm trying to figure out why. (That is not what I'm asking). I usually go to GDB to find out what went wrong but literally at the start of my program it keeps crashing with this message.

__strcmp_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../strcmp.S:34

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Prototypes and linked lists here

int debugMode(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(strcmp(argv[argc-1], "-d") == 0) // GDB stops right here.
       return 1;

    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int debug, integer;
    char choice;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *current;

    debug = debugMode(argc, argv);
    // stuff here
}
```

Keep in mind I do have a function prototype. Thanks for your help.

Edit: btw I'm not sending any arguments. I'm using redirection to figure out what is causing my program to do an infinite loop.

Comment: I didn't send arguments... Sorry for not be clear. I edited my post. Anyways I think something is wrong with my gdb.. I commented that part out and now it's crashing with another part randomly. It should not be crashing at all :\.

Comment: did you compile which -g flag ?

Comment: yes i did is that bad?

Comment: gcc -g ccarri7lab9.c -o ccarri7lab9 was the command I did

Comment: No, it is not bad. I did the same thing in my PC and it works

Comment: Ok thanks I'm working on my laptop.. I have ubuntu installed on my pc so I'll just do it there and see if it works. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you're not copying across compiled programs from laptop to pc or vice-versa are you?  you could be mixing 32 and 64 bit code, which might cause this (guessing wildly).

Comment: Nope 64 bit OS on both. It works on my desktop.. something is wrong with GDB on my laptop. I'll figure it out later I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> keeps crashing with this message.

```
__strcmp_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../strcmp.S:34
```

Your version of glibc has this (recently fixed) bug: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13786

(Note: sourceware.org is down this week for hardware upgrades, if you get a "no route" to it, try again later.)